# How to send message to just created channel?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to make nuke command in my bot, but i have one problem: How can I make bot sending message, to just created channel?
Here's my code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete()
    await ctx.channel.clone(reason="Channel has been nuked")

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f':boom: CHAT ({ctx.channel.name}) HAS BEEN CLEARED :boom:',
        description=f'By: **@{user.name}#{user.discriminator}**',
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def nuke(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.delete()
    new_channel = await ctx.channel.clone(reason="Channel has been nuked")

    embed = discord.Embed(
        title=f':boom: CHAT ({ctx.channel.name}) HAS BEEN CLEARED :boom:',
        description=f'By: **@{user.name}#{user.discriminator}**',
        colour=discord.Colour.blue()
    )
    embed.set_footer(text=f"{ctx.guild.name}  •  {datetime.strftime(datetime.now(), '%d.%m.%Y at %I:%M %p')}")

    await new_channel.send(embed=embed)
```

This should work !

Comment: Maybe you should clone the channel before delete it.